# Upload file to a publicly writeable folder on Google Drive - using Python and without going thru the authentication?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-drive-api

The [python sample source code](https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/python#complete_source_code) goes thru the details of authentication/etc. I am looking for a simple upload to the Google Drive folder that has public writable permissions. (Plan to implement authorization at a later point).

I want to replace the below code to upload file to Google Drive folder instead.

```
f = open('output.txt')
for line in allLines:
       f.write (line)
f.close()
```

(If it makes any difference, I plan to run this thru Google App Engine).

Thanks.

Comment: And its even the first sentence of the api doc ;)

Comment: Thanks Wooble! The document also states that it is possible to get long-lived tokens, which I am assuming will allow to do batch'ed uploads, without going thru a UI or user-interaction.

Comment: @Wooble: Can you make this an answer to the question? It'll help to mark it as answered.

Comment: Wooble, do you still want me to do this ? Btw, I have posted [another related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11432742/replace-openssl-in-oauth2client-crypt-to-work-with-pycrypto) in line with being able to get the Cert/(server-to-server) based Oauth2.0 to work on app-engine..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. All requests to the Drive API need authentication (source: http://developers.google.com/drive/about_auth)

Comment: Current Python samples for Google Drive Access, are thru the Drive SDK and are assuming a UI based interaction. I am looking to use OAuth 2.0 via a certificate-based authentication for server-to-server interactions. So something like for [task](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/source/browse/samples/service_account/tasks.py) that wraps google drive service. Thanks. (Shall I post this as a separate question ?)

Comment: Could I use 'build("drive", "v1", http=http)' in the [task example](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/source/browse/samples/service_account/tasks.py) in place of  'service = build("tasks", "v1", http=http)' ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As Wooble said, you cannot do this without authentication. You can use this service + file-upload widget to let your website visitors upload files to your Google Drive folder: https://github.com/cloudwok/file-upload-embed/