# Replace OpenSSL in oauth2client.crypt to work with PyCrypto

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, pycrypto, google-api-client, pyopenssl

Google App Engine supports [PyCrypto](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries#PyCrypto), but does not support OpenSSL.

I want to use the oauth2client SignedJwtAssertionCredentials, which internally calls OpenSSL . Is there is a way to get oauth2client to work with PyCrypto.

I am assuming that it might be possible to create a local version of SignedJwtAssertionCredential equivalent by using PyCrypto instead ?

Also is there a way I can make a request to Google App Engine to provide a version that support the functionality for certificate/Assertions for server-to-server Oauth2.0 dance ?

Any pointers/help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Were you able to fix this problem? Please share the solution. I am having a similar issue http://stackoverflow.com/q/25571504/1443563

Answer (score 0):

Found this link and this avoids any special handling to avoid ssl/etc.. This link has [Google Data support for App Engine use](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/python/retrieving_gdata_feeds).

I have not tried it yet - but once I use it, I will share feedback, if worthwhile for others.