# PyCrypto Errors with .p12 file from Google Developer Console

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, pycrypto, oauth2client

I am trying to implement Google Identity Toolkit (gitkitv3) in GAE Python. After a user signs in on the website, I get the following errors:

```
'PKCS12 format is not supported by the PyCrpto library. '
NotImplementedError: PKCS12 format is not supported by the PyCrpto library. Try converting to a "PEM" (openssl pkcs12 -in xxxxx.p12 -nodes -nocerts > privatekey.pem) or using PyOpenSSL if native code is an option.
```

Based on [a SO reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25190067/1443563), I ran the following commands on my x.p12 file and used the generated privatekey.pem file instead:

```
openssl pkcs12 -passin pass:notasecret -in x.p12 -nocerts -passout pass:notasecret -out key.pem 
openssl pkcs8 -nocrypt -in key.pem -passin pass:notasecret -topk8 -out privatekey.pem
```

Now, I am getting the following error:

```
'X509 certs are not supported by the PyCrypto library. '
NotImplementedError: X509 certs are not supported by the PyCrypto library. Try using PyOpenSSL if native code is an option.
```

I had downloaded the x.p12 from Google Developer Console. How to fix this error? Please help

---

**ANY WORKAROUND?**

Do I necessarily need this file .p12 file or can I copy its contents to a global variable and use it (as a workaround)?
Could someone please explain me the actual use of this file?

---

**UPDATE**
Looks like PyCrypto library provided by Google is extremely limited and lacks capability to support X509.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17993604/signedjwtassertioncredentials-on-appengine-doesnt-recognize-pem-key

Comment: @Bruyere Thanks but I have already tried that and it did not work.

Comment: Including removing the hearder "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----" ?

Comment: @Bruyere I tried that now and I am got the first error mentioned above `NotImplementedError: PKCS12 format is not supported by the PyCrpto library.. `

Comment: PyCrypto does not support X.509 certs at all. You can still load them as indicated here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12911373/how-do-i-use-a-x509-certificate-with-pycrypto. Mind that a private key is not an x.509 cert (which includes the public key). It is not clear what your code needs though.

Comment: @SquareRootOfTwentyThree Thanks for your suggestion. I went through the question and your answer. I am not able to figure out at which all places and what all to change myself since I am not comfortable with code in [oauth2client/crypt.py](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/downloads/detail?name=google-api-python-client-gae-1.2.zip&can=2&q=).

Comment: @SquareRootOfTwentyThree I tried your solution but am getting some [new errors](http://pastebin.com/hcWgnXYn)

Comment: @gsinha Have you extracted the X509 cert with a command like `openssl pkcs12 -clcerts -nokeys -in mycert.p12 -out usercert.pem`? Can you post the cert somewhere?

Comment: @SquareRootOfTwentyThree I got present .pem by:
`openssl pkcs12 -in <key.p12> -nocerts -passin pass:notasecret -nodes -out <key.pem>`
key.pem:
`Bag Attributes
    friendlyName: privatekey
    localKeyID: 54 69 6D 65 20 31 34 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 30
Key Attributes: <No Attributes>
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
lots_of_characters_present_here_replaced_for_this_post=
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
`
Next, I deleted first 4 lines of .pem file. Final .pem looks like:
`-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
lots_of_characters_are_present_here_which_i_have_replaced_for_this_post=
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----`

Comment: @gsinha The code that fails performs a verification, and for that you need a public key, not a private key. Could you try the command from my previous comment? That gives you a public key (inside an X.509 cert).

Comment: @SquareRootOfTwentyThree I generated the new certificate using `openssl pkcs12 -clcerts -nokeys -in myapp-36.p12 -out usercert.pem`. The generated certificate could be seen [here](http://pastebin.com/RGtfGdiy) (replaced sensitive data). I tried and got [this error](http://pastebin.com/zKpYyg0F). Then I removed everything before "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----" and tried again. The new certificate is [here](http://pastebin.com/R0tv1wBj). This time, I got [this error](http://pastebin.com/yfsFYJ1q).

Comment: Hi gsinha, i've been having the same problem. Can you tell me how you managed to work arround it ?

Comment: @user3824957 The experimental version of PyCrypto had the fix. It has also been incorporated in GAE Production some time ago. [This](https://groups.google.com/forum/embed/?place=forum/google-identity-toolkit&showsearch=true&showpopout=true&parenturl=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fidentity-toolkit%2Fforum#!topic/google-identity-toolkit/fvPwCd1Dhjs) is the Gitkit discussion thread. I had raised [an issue](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11257&can=4&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log) with GAE too.

Comment: @gsinha : I am facing the same issue. Did you get any work around ? If yes please share.

Comment: @Kartik This issue had been fixed by Google a few months ago.

Comment: @gsinha : yeah. Its working now though I didn't change anything.

Answer (score 8):

Installing `pyopenssl` fixed the issue for me:

```
pip install pyopenssl
```

Comment: Where do I run this command? On my mac/local machine and then include the pyopenssl package in the app.yaml before uploading to GAE?