# Import Error: Google Analytics API Authorization

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to run the sample provided here https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-py for authorization.

I've noticed from other questions in SO that ([ImportError: cannot import name SignedJwtAssertionCredentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14063124/importerror-cannot-import-name-signedjwtassertioncredentials)) SignedJwtAssertionCredentials has been removed and therefore could not be imported.

So, I started to follow the solutions provided both on the GitHub page (https://github.com/google/oauth2client/issues/401) and StackOverflow. So far, nothing worked, I'm still seeing the same error. Following is my code.

```
import argparse

from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

import httplib2
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import file
from oauth2client import tools
```

And, this is the error I'm receiving on running the above code.

```
ImportError: cannot import name ServiceAccountCredentials
```

As I'm a complete newbie in this space, I tried to do this for both versions of `OAuth` (2.0.0 and 1.5.2). I also tried it after installing `pyopenssl`, but still failed.

Comment: Can you include the output of `import oauth2client; oauth2client.__version__`?

Comment: `import oauth2client`

`oauth2client.__version__?`
`Type:        str
String form: 2.0.0-post1
Length:      11
Docstring:
str(object='') -> string`

`Return a nice string representation of the object.
If the argument is a string, the return value is the same object.`

Comment: The problem somehow seems solved now. I just tried a few hours later and it worked.

Answer (score 15):

It seems oauth2client installation is unsuccessful. Try

> pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client

Comment: It is successfully installed. 2.0.0. version.

Comment: There could be many reasons for this to not work. Check this link for the things which could go wrong. http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html

Answer (score 2):

Installing `pyopenssl` fixed the issue for me:

```
pip install pyopenssl
```

Based on [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28872094/1224827)

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues where I was getting `cannot import name xxxx` error.  It turn out I had old *.pyc files in my environment from an older oauth2client version.  Even though I updated to the lastest oauth2client version, the *.pyc files were getting used when I tried to run.  I simply deleted the oauth2client *.pyc files and then reran my program without any issues.

Even if you upgrade to use the latest google-api-python-client... you'll want to make sure any *.pyc files from the old library have been removed.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue in python3.

My python packages were a little bit messy and broken, because I was using python2 (being default one) and python3 and I was not using virtualenv. My os was Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie). I had exactcly the same issue:

`ImportError: cannot import name ServiceAccountCredentials`

Before I have fixed it, my packages were like this in python3:

```
Python 3.4.2 (default, Feb  7 2019, 06:08:06)
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import oauth2client
>>> oauth2client.__version__
'1.5.2'
```

I had to uninstall every pip installation:

```
sudo pip uninstall pip
sudo pip3 uninstall pip
sudo python -m pip uninstall pip
sudo python3 -m pip uninstall pip
```

I had to install pip3 with easy_install:

```
sudo easy_install3 pip
```

I had also to uninstall oauth2client:

```
sudo pip3 uninstall oauth2client
```

It also turned out there was some files under `~/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/oauth2client/` in my home directory, so I executed the following command from my current user (not root) to delete the directory:

```
rm -rf ~/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/oauth2client*
```

I have installed oauth2client:

```
sudo pip3 uninstall oauth2client
```

After that the issue was resolved. Please note that while it was resolved on my local system, the other systems might need different solution (for example, python temporary files might be in a different path). However, the main approach is to have only 1 pip module, 1 oauth2client installation and be sure that there are no conflicting or temporary files that might affect current python3 environment.

```
Python 3.4.2 (default, Feb  7 2019, 06:08:06)
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux
>>> import oauth2client
>>> oauth2client.__version__
'4.1.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

My 2cents:

For this to work I had to install and update these packages either

-from WITHIN the NORMAL TERMINAL with PLAIN PYTHON, no distribution such as Conda(don't forget to set Path-Variable):

```
py -m pip install google-api-python-client
py -m pip install oauth2client
```

-or from WITHIN the CONDA TERMINAL with:

```
pip install google-api-python-client oauth2client
pip install --upgrade oauth2client  #important
```

this did NOT WORK when I tried to install and update from jupyter notebook with pip